# Showing that the tensor product of vector spaces is closed under addition

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over the field $F$. We know that $V\otimes W$ is a vector space over $F$.

But how do we show closure under addition? For instance let $(a\otimes b), (c\otimes d)\in V\otimes W$. How do we know that $(a\otimes b)+(c\otimes d)\in V\otimes W$?

Comment: What is your definition of $V\otimes W$?

Comment: @EricWofsey- It is the initial object in the category of all $F$- vector spaces to which $V\times W$ has a bilinear map. I was thinking along the same lines: is $V\otimes W$ **defined** to be closed under addition? Or is there an element $(m\otimes n)\in V\otimes W$ such that $(m\otimes n)=(a\otimes b)+(c\otimes d)$?

Comment: Elements of $V\otimes W$ are not all of the form $a\otimes b$ for $a\in V$ and $b\in W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $V\otimes W$ is defined to be a vector space, it is closed under addition by definition.  However, not every element of $V\otimes W$ is of the form $v\otimes w$.  All we know from the definition is that there is a bilinear map $\mu:V\times W\to V\otimes W$ satisfying a certain universal property, and we write $\mu(v,w)=v\otimes w$.  The map $\mu$ need not be surjective, and its image need not be closed under addition.  So you can't necessarily write $a\otimes b+c\otimes d$ in the form $m\otimes n$.  In general, all that you can say is that every element of $V\otimes W$ can be written as a sum $v_1\otimes w_1+v_2\otimes w_2+\dots+v_n\otimes w_n$.

Comment: Thanks! That cleared up a lot